# Django Apps extendability - How to make your django apps easily extendable?

Tags: python, django

What are your best practises for making your django application easily extendable for other developers?

What are your approaches for enabling other to overwrite your

- views
- forms
- templates
- models
- classes

In a way that enables a healthy environment for extensions to work well together?

Answer (score 1):

1. use signals and dispatchers

in your app create files..
           -litseners.py
           -signals.py
and then implement signals for your models and forms (views not so much)

1. use the django plugins pattern
2. ducktyping for your classes

Comment: use the django plugins pattern
-- what do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [what he says](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4). But [class based views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) in Django 1.3 will change this pretty much. See [Alex Gaynor's talk](http://djangocon.blip.tv/file/4108781/) for an in-depth analysis of what class based views will bring to reusable apps.